# Qt 'qHash': none of the 23 overloads could convert all the argument types

Tags: c++, qt

I am working on plugin development for a tool called Techlog and the tool provides SDK for the development of the plugin.
It uses Qt for the UI.
I am trying to include a header file given by the SDK as shown below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tsdkvariable.h>

using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    cout << "Hello World\n";
}
```

When I include the file and try to build, I am getting the below error.
Not getting how to proceed further.

```
error C2665: 'qHash': none of the 23 overloads could convert all the argument types
3rdparty\qt 5.15.2\include\qtcore\qhashfunctions.h(108): note: could be 'uint qHash(std::nullptr_t,uint) noexcept'
3rdparty\qt 5.15.2\include\qtcore\qhashfunctions.h(105): note: or       'uint qHash(QLatin1String,uint) noexcept'
3rdparty\qt 5.15.2\include\qtcore\qhashfunctions.h(104): note: or       'uint qHash(const QBitArray &,uint) noexcept'
3rdparty\qt 5.15.2\include\qtcore\qhashfunctions.h(103): note: or       'uint qHash(QStringView,uint) noexcept'
3rdparty\qt 5.15.2\include\qtcore\qhashfunctions.h(101): note: or       'uint qHash(const QStringRef &,uint) noexcept'
3rdparty\qt 5.15.2\include\qtcore\qhashfunctions.h(100): note: or       'uint qHash(const QString &,uint) noexcept'
3rdparty\qt 5.15.2\include\qtcore\qhashfunctions.h(98): note: or       'uint qHash(const QByteArray &,uint) noexcept'
3rdparty\qt 5.15.2\include\qtcore\qhashfunctions.h(97): note: or       'uint qHash(const QChar,uint) noexcept'
3rdparty\qt 5.15.2\include\qtcore\qhashfunctions.h(95): note: or       'uint qHash(long double,uint) noexcept'
3rdparty\qt 5.15.2\include\qtcore\qhashfunctions.h(93): note: or       'uint qHash(double,uint) noexcept'
3rdparty\qt 5.15.2\include\qtcore\qhashfunctions.h(92): note: or       'uint qHash(float,uint) noexcept'
3rdparty\qt 5.15.2\include\qtcore\qhashfunctions.h(91): note: or       'uint qHash(qint64,uint) noexcept'
3rdparty\qt 5.15.2\include\qtcore\qhashfunctions.h(87): note: or       'uint qHash(quint64,uint) noexcept'
1>c:\program files\schlumberger\ocean for techlog 2022.1\3rdparty\qt 5.15.2\include\qtcore\qhash.h(291): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void QHash<T,QHashDummyValue>::detach_helper(void)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=Slb::Ocean::Techlog::Droid
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\stdexcept(23): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' being compiled
1>c:\program files\schlumberger\ocean for techlog 2022.1\3rdparty\qt 5.15.2\include\qtcore\qhashfunctions.h(118): error C2056: illegal expression
```

The qt which comes with SDK doesn't have the qmake...
[image]

Comment: Know nothing about this, but a very quick look at the documentation and it seems they use Qt 5.12.3. You are clearly using a different version of Qt. Just a theory.

Comment: New version of the SDK uses Qt 5.15.2

Comment: 1>c:\program files\schlumberger\ocean for techlog 2022.1\3rdparty\qt 5.15.2\include\qtcore\qhash.h(291): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void QHash<T,QHashDummyValue>::detach_helper(void)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=Slb::Ocean::Techlog::Droid
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\stdexcept(23): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' being compiled

Comment: Ok, try this instead of your current code: `#include <QHash> #include <iostream> int main(){ QHash<int, int> foo = { {1, 1} }; std::cout << foo[1] << std::endl; }`

Comment: Seems like you are missing an overload for ```Slb::Ocean::Techlog::Droid```. See if they overload ```qHash``` in one of their other headers. Maybe you are not meant to include ```<tsdkvariable.h>``` on its own.

Comment: Also please tell what exact version of Qt you are using, and also what exact compiler and version. You can get information with `qmake -query` if you are unsure.

Comment: @hyde: I am getting same error after running your code...

Comment: Then issue is clearly with your Qt setup. Double-check Qt vs compiler versions, at least.

Comment: And it could also be your project files, which ever build system you are using. It could have wrong paths or something.

Comment: My suspicion would be wrong MSVC (that's what you'te using, right?) version.

Comment: Yes, I am using MSVC... Will check again for the documentation...

Comment: Got the issue fixed by enabling "Conformance Mode" under Project->Properties->C/C++->Language->Conformance Mode